# How to turn on Xbox One from Windows 10 PC using Cortana?

Tags: microsoft-windows, wake-on-lan, microsoft-xbox, cortana

[Cortana](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/cortana) is Microsoft's intelligent personal assistant for Windows Phone 8.1, Microsoft Band, and Windows 10.

I am interested in how can someone turn on their Xbox One by using Cortana voice command. Unfortunately when I was searching in the topic I only found articles about how to turn on Cortana on the Xbox itself. In my case Cortana should listen on my PC running Windows 10.

If possible I want to avoid [serious scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30431688/how-to-connect-cortana-commands-to-custom-scripts) and such for first and I hope that there is a more sophisticated solution, if only because all of these are Microsoft products.

Comment: I assume you log-in on the same account with your Xbox and PC?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wake-on-LAN is relatively new for the Xbox One. This feature was released with the August update.

Luckily, you don't have to script yourself a solution. Others have already done the work for you:

- [Xbox on](https://github.com/arcreative/xbox-on) by *arcreative*: Xbox One power control from CLI or Node.JS application.
- [Xbox remote power](https://github.com/Schamper/xbox-remote-power) by *Schamper*: A script that can turn your Xbox One on remotely.

If you're interested in figuring out something for yourself, [this technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb932199.aspx) is a must-read.

I must admit, I'm a little disappointed I couldn't find a completely integrated method of communicating with your Xbox One from a PC or phone with Windows 10. Both PC and Windows phone have an Xbox app after all.

'Teaching' Cortana to recognize and execute custom scripts has been explained [in this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31387719).

Comment: All this is only possible when Xbox is set to "instant-on"? Or are there solutions wo take it up from power saving mode?

Comment: @ciB I don't know, but I'd hazard a guess and say it needs to be on 'instant-on'. It has to accept and act on 'power on' packets. I can imagine it won't in power saving mode, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4):

**Without Cortana**

1. By using the Xbox button on your controller if your controller is paired to your Xbox One.
2. By using the official Windows 10 Microsoft Xbox app. To make this work, you have to connect your Xbox One to the Windows 10 app by following [these steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mi22q.png). If streaming works, your Xbox One is connected to your Windows 10 Xbox app. Now shutdown your Xbox One. You should still see your Xbox listed in the Windows 10 Xbox app. It now should also offer you an option to turn on your Xbox One see screenshot below), and there you have it! :)

Notice: I only tested this on my Xbox One connected by LAN, Xbox One configured in high energy mode and with the Windows 10 Xbox app version 38.38.14002.00000. Comments if this works on WiFi and on low energy settings are welcome.

A screenshot (in dutch) of what this looks like:

[image]

**With Cortana**

I don't think Cortana supports waking your xbox by using your voice nativly so you need a 3th party script or app. The script or app should use the wake-on-lan protocol and target your xbox one MAC adres to wake it. [This guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y6xTyuLixKg) has a video about cortana waking his pc, it should also work with your xbox one.

Another option might want to look into is using IFTT with the Cortana integration and some other wake-on-lan integration. [This](https://ifttt.com/applets/480537p-turn-on-xbox-with-google-assistant) is an example to wake your xbox one by using Google Assistant. You might create your own working applet without any scripting at all.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Is there a way to use Cortana with the methods you're suggesting, as Bence asked in the question? I think the question was specifically thinking about voice control if possible.

Comment: Ah I missed that important point in the question and title, how stupid of me. :) I think Windows 10 with cortana does not offer the functionality to wake your Xbox One remotely so you're likely to need a script. However... you should be able to wake your Xbox One with a simple Wake-On-Lan signal that works on other devices too, this is an opening. This guy has a youtube tutorial how to implement Wake-On-Lan with Cortana for his PC but it should work well on a Xbox One too if you know the MAC adres of your Xbox One: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y6xTyuLixKg

Comment: @Aurora0001 thx I updated my post. Left the original stuff in too since it might be usefull for somebody.

Answer (score 3):

For reference here is some C# [Universal Windows Platform](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/whats-a-uwp) (UWP) code that I wrote to wake up an Xbox One:

```cs
public static async Task XboxWake(IPAddress ipAddress, string liveId, int retries = 5)
{
    using (var socket = new DatagramSocket())
    {
        var connectionProfile = Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
        await socket.BindServiceNameAsync("", connectionProfile.NetworkAdapter);

        using (var stream = await socket.GetOutputStreamAsync(new HostName(ipAddress.ToString()), "5050"))
        {
            using (var writer = new DataWriter(stream))
            {
                for (int retry = 0; retry < retries; retry++)
                {
                    byte[] payload = new byte[3 + liveId.Length];
                    payload[0] = 0x00;
                    payload[1] = (byte)liveId.Length;

                    for (int i = 0; i < liveId.Length; i++)
                        payload[i + 2] = (byte)liveId[i];
                    payload[payload.Length - 1] = 0x00;

                    byte[] header = new byte[6];
                    header[0] = 0xdd;
                    header[1] = 0x02;
                    header[2] = 0x00;
                    header[3] = (byte)payload.Length;
                    header[4] = 0x00;
                    header[5] = 0x00;

                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(header.Length + payload.Length))
                    {
                        ms.Write(header, 0, header.Length);
                        ms.Write(payload, 0, payload.Length);

                        writer.WriteBytes(ms.ToArray());
                    }
                    await writer.StoreAsync();

                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

([GitHub Gist link of the above code](https://gist.github.com/HakanL/48cdc64a032445a9881b70fa11f43972))

Comment: Welcome. I edited in your Gist code directly into the answer in case the link breaks in future — [we generally discourage answers that are just links elsewhere on Stack Exchange](https://iot.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), so I've edited in the important information for you. I'm sure this code will be useful for anyone hoping to develop an app to do this though.

Comment: I appreciate the edit, I was lazy ;)

Answer (score 2):

I have developed a (paid) app called XBoot One that you can use it to turn on your Xbox remotely both in Android and Windows. It's not integrated with Cortana yet but it will be in future releases.

[Play Store Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mehradsoft.XBootOne)

It will be in Microsoft Store soon.

Comment: Are you the developer of this app? If so, [you need to disclose this in your answer](https://iot.stackexchange.com/help/promotion), particularly since this app is paid. Sharing links to relevant products you're involved with isn't a problem, but doing it without making it clear could be seen as improper.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just updated my answer to address the point you kindly made.